# How to IEnumerable.GroupBy<T> with 3 different "qualities" getting count in C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, grouping, generic-collections

I want to group by a list of objects inherited from an abstract class  by:

1. Type of item in list (in this example MyAction or MyObservation)
2. An integer attribute ClassId
3. A string attribute Value

And get a count out those groups.

```
public abstract class MyData
{
    public int ClassId;
    public string Value;
    //...
}

public class MyAction : MyData
{
    //...
}

public class MyObservation : MyData
{
    //...
}

// in some class...
IEnumerable<MyData> _myDatas;

void TryGroupBy()
{
    var result = _myDatas.GroupBy(
               data => KeySelector(data), /* ?? key is 3 pieces of info */,
               data => ElementSelector/* ?? I didn't get this either */,
               (row, rows) => new 
               {
                   ClassId = ?? /*how to get it from 3 piece key */
                   TypeOfObject = /* how to get it ?? */
                   Value = /* how to get it ?? */
                   Count = rows.Count
               }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type as key and then access the properties using `Key` property (e.g. `group.Key.Id`), or you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx) which will give you the key as first argument of result selector:

```
_myDatas.GroupBy(
           data => new { Type = data.GetType(), Id = data.ClassId, Value = data.Value },
           (key, rows) => new 
           {
               ClassId = key.Id,
               TypeOfObject = key.Type,
               Value = key.Value,
               Count = rows.Count()
           }));
```

Comment: Takes maybe few hours to fix the code around it to able to really test it. I will accept it, when verified.